# Get a relative path with jquery .attr() property with IE7

Tags: jquery

This code gets the path in all browsers - except ie7, when it returns the full url

```
$(selector).attr('href');
```

How do I adapt this code to always return the path?

```
/foo/bar/x.html
```

not

```
http://www.sample.com/foo/bar/x.html
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like IE7 is the only browser doing it *right*. What does the original attribute look like?

Comment: It's a path `<a href="/path/foo/">link</a>`

Comment: @BozKey not a full solution, but does `$(selector)[0].href` return anything different?

Comment: @pekka that returns the full url consistently - I'm after the opposite. To return the path only consistently

Comment: yeah. IE7 seems to be serving the computed URL instead of the raw attribute, which is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(selector).attr('href').replace('http://'+window.location.hostname,'')
```

Comment: Hoping for a more elegant jquery solution - but this does the trick

Comment: This may solve the problem at hand, but is fairly kludgy. It would be much more desirable to find a way to make IE7 return the original raw attribute. (Not sure such a way exists, though.)